# Change text in another activity on click. how?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I am new to this forum as an User, and I am also new to Java and Android, in developing ways. Sorry if there are any language or other mistakes.

So I am trying to make an app for a 'final' school project, which has the follow use:

The user sees a picture, a 'next' and a 'finish' button. there are 11 pictures (user only sees one) when the user clicks 'next', the pic no. 2 appears, if he clicks another time next, the picture no. 3 appears and so on. 
when user clicks next 2 times (so if he made it until the 3rd picture) and then clicks finish, he'll Return to the main activity, and instead of the text 'Klicke auf start um zu beginnen' (click on start to begin) the text 'you made it until the 3rd picture' should show up. 
If he clicked Next 5 times (6th picture) and clicks finish, he also returns to the main activity, but the text is 'you made it until the 5th picture'. 
And so on with the others.

I've tried this, but I failed.

the red lines are those, which I made at my own but they unfortunately don't work

[B]Java Main Activity[/B]

```
package ch.OptiLab.visustest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView textView;

    Button btn1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSTART);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);




    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,VisusActivity.class), 0);

    }
public void onActivityResult() {
    if (resultCode == R.drawable.v1)textView.setText("you got 01");
    else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v2)textView.setText("you got 02");
    else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v3)textView.setText("you got 03");
    else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v4)textView.setText("you got 04");
    else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v5)textView.setText("you got 05");
    else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v6)textView.setText("you got 06");
    else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v7)textView.setText("you got 07");
    else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v8)textView.setText("you got 08");
    else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v9)textView.setText("you got 09");
    else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v10)textView.setText("you got 10");



}

]
```

XML Main Activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="(external link)"
    xmlns:tools="(external link)"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ch.OptiLab.visustest.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/Text1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/Text2"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSTART"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="142dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java 2nd activity

```
 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;




    public class VisusActivity extends Activity {
        Button next;
        ImageView testanzeige;
        Button finish;
        int i = 0;



     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_visus);
        next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        testanzeige = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.testanzeige);
        finish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.finish);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);


        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

 @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                i++;
                // To Set Your 1 Image Do it Thorough Layout


                if (i == 1 ) {
                    //Your 2 Image
                    testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v1);


                    onStop();

                    setResult(R.drawable.v1);




                }
                else if (i == 2) {
                    //Your 3 Image
                    testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v2);

onStop();

                    setResult(R.drawable.v2);
                }
                else if (i == 3) {
                    //Your 4 Image
                    testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v3);

onStop();

                    setResult(R.drawable.v3);
                }
                else if (i == 4) {
                    // Your 5 Image
                    //Imagey.setImageResource(R.drawable.Your Image);
                    testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v4);

onStop();

                    setResult(R.drawable.v4);
                }
                else if (i == 5 ) {
                    //Your 6 Image
                    //Imagey.setImageResource(R.drawable.Your Image);
                    testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v5);

onStop();

                    setResult(R.drawable.v5);
                }
                else if (i == 6) {
                    //Your 7 Image
                    //Imagey.setImageResource(R.drawable.Your Image);
                    testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v6);

onStop();

                    setResult(R.drawable.v6);
                }
                else if (i == 7 ) {
                    //Your 8 Image
                    //Imagey.setImageResource(R.drawable.Your Image);
                    testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v7);

onStop();

                    setResult(R.drawable.v7);
                }
                else if (i == 8 ) {
                    //Your 9 Image
                    //Imagey.setImageResource(R.drawable.Your Image);
                    testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v8);

onStop();

                    setResult(R.drawable.v8);
                }
                else if (i == 9) {
                    //Your 10 Image
                    testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v9);

onStop();

                    setResult(R.drawable.v9);
                }
                else if (i == 10) {
                    //Image 11 Image
                    testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.v10);

onStop();

                    setResult(R.drawable.v10);
                //next.setText("Finish");
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Final Text", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                }

                finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        finish();

                    }

                });



                }

        });




}




}
```

XML 2nd Activity

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/testanzeige"
        android:layout_width="231dp"
        android:layout_height="231dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/v2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/NEXTPIC" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/finish"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/next"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/next"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/cantread" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The most important strings:

```
 <string name="Text1">Klicke auf Start um zu beginnen.</string>
<string name="cantread">finish</string>
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `startActivityForResult` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

You pass two parameters in this function. For the purpose of this example lets assume you pass `2` as the result code.

Now when you're about to finish your second activity, and before you call `finish()` you can use `setResult(position)` where `position` is the image position that you just set. After you call finish your main activity will fire `onActivityResult`.

On that method you will have to search for the `requestCode` that you passed (2) and you will get the result code that you used on your `setResult`.

You can also pass bundles with this method.

**EDIT**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == R.drawable.v1)textView.setText("you got 01");
else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v2)textView.setText("you got 02");
else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v3)textView.setText("you got 03");
else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v4)textView.setText("you got 04");
else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v5)textView.setText("you got 05");
else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v6)textView.setText("you got 06");
else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v7)textView.setText("you got 07");
else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v8)textView.setText("you got 08");
else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v9)textView.setText("you got 09");
else if (resultCode == R.drawable.v10)textView.setText("you got 10");
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you, all of you and sorry for my noobish conduct.

I almost got it, but I don't know how to use it with the finish button and to implement the new text, i made this, but I think its wrong:


if (i == 1 ) {
     //Your 2 Image
     testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.visustest);
     
       startActivityForResult(
         setResult(position),
                      MainActivity.class);
                     
              
      
    }
    e

Comment: No friend. You only call `startActivityForResult` on the first activity. Instead of a simple `startActivity`. On your second activity you just have to call `setResult(position)` and then call `finish()`. Once you call finish your MainActivity will call `onActivityResult` with the code you passed on your second activity. You will need to override that method.

Comment: I got it!..halfway. thank you so very much for your mildness. :: testanzeige.setImageResource(R.drawable.visustest);setResult(R.drawable.visustest); finish();  :: this is very good, but how can I effect, that it only finishes on 'finish' buttonclick? :::: @Override
 public void onActivityResult() {
  if (resultCode == visustest);
  textView.setText("you got 01");
 }
  :::: and idk... doesnt work i'm too stupid at the moment :'(     do you have an email adress to contact you so I could probably pay you a beer or 2 for your insane help?

Comment: I'm not understanding your question. Could you please update your code on your answer and tell us what is happening? Btw, you're passing `R.drawable.visustes‌​t` which is an id of a drawable. Also remove the if from your `onActivityResult` and print your resultCode so you see what is getting passed to there

Comment: changed the code in the main question, in main- and second activity, and directly wrote the /*questions*/ in it at the 2 problem parts

Comment: Don't call `finish()` on your button click. Instead override your `onStop` and call `setResult` there.

Comment: Implement a onClickListener on your `finish` button and just call `finish()`. It will call `onStop` by itself

Comment: Thank you very very much!! works fine(edited 2nd activity), now my last question: exactly: how can I  now by the different result change the text in different textes by result in the main activity?  I know you told me but the way i did it didnt work.     btw. you saved my whole life!!! thank you

Comment: Depends of what text you want to set. The current content that will get passed to the main activity is `R.drawable.vX`. That's an integer. So you can for example create an if on your `onActivityResult` like this: `if(resultCode == R.drawable.v3)textView.setText("you got 3")`.

Comment: i changed now the main activity, but it shows me the error: resultCode cannot be resoved as an Variable. :(

Comment: works fine in eclipse, no errors, but when I start it on my sony, it crashes. I surrounded your code with a try, catch block, bun i dont know what exatly to do now.

Comment: Because your textview is null. From what I've seen this is pretty basic error that you should be able to solve yourself. Since I'm not here to do your homework for you I will not solve any other problem. Best of luck and if you keep getting other errors I suggest you star another question.

Comment: thank you a lot for your help. I appreciate it very very much. My school doesn't teach stuff like that, I tried all this at my own for a degree work which has nothing to do with my job. Thank you a lot, have a nice weekend.

   you were right, it was a basic error, solved it now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the last image shown's index for `finish` button :

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
in.putExtra("index", i);
startActivity(in);
```

And in your `MainActivity` `onCreate`, check if the data is passed :

```
Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
if(data != null)
   int lastIndex = data.getInt("index");
```

After this, you can do anything with `lastIndex`, like show it in your `TextView`.